# How to access each string in the lists of list

Tags: python, list

I was given a task to input multiple lines each consisting of multiple words.The task is to uppercase the words with an odd length and lowercase the words with an
even length.
 My code now looks like this, can you help me to solve it right?

```
first = []
while True:

    line = input().split()
    first.append(line)
    if len(line) < 1:
        break
for i in first:
    for j in i:
        if len(line[i][j]) % 2 == 0:
            line[i][j] = line[i][j].lower()
        elif len(line[i][j]) % 2 != 0:
            line[i][j] = line[i][j].upper()
         print(first[i])
```

[it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiGHC.png)

Comment: You forgot to join the lines back together.

Comment: `can you help me to solve it right?` is broad. What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`i` and `j` are not an indexes, they are the sublists and words themselves.You can do:

```
for i in first:  # i is a list of strings
    for j in range(len(i)):  # you do need the index to mutate the list
        if len(i[j]) % 2 == 0:
            i[j] = i[j].lower()
        else:
            i[j] = i[j].upper()
        print(' '.join(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

So looking at the input output in your image, here is a better solution

```
sentences = []
while True:
    word_list = input().split()
    sentences = [*sentences, word_list]
    if len(word_list) < 1:
        break
```

So now that you have your input from command line you can do

```
[word.upper() if len(word)%2 == 1 else word.lower() for word_list in sentences for word in word_list]
```

or you could extract into a function

```
def apply_case(word):
  if len(word)%2:
    return word.upper()
  return word.lower()

new_sentences = [apply_case(word) for word_list in sentences for word in word_list]
```

now you can print it like

```
output = "\n".join([" ".join(word_list) for word_list in new_sentences])
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to join the lines back together. Furthermore from a *software design* point of view, you are doing to much in the code fragment: it is better to encapsulate the functionalities in functions, like:

```
def wordcase(word):
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:  # even
        return word.lower()
    else:                   # odd
        return word.upper()
```

Then we can even perform the processing "online" (as in line-per-line):

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    else:
        print(' '.join(wordcase(word) for word in line.split()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need do be using `i` or `j`. You can just loop over the words in your string.

Further, although it probably won't speed things up, you don't need the `elif`, you can just use an `else`. There are only two options, odd and even so you only need to check it once.

```
sentance = 'I am using this as a test string with many words'

wordlist = sentance.split()
fixed_wordlist = []

for word in wordlist:
    if len(word)%2==0:
        fixed_wordlist.append(word.lower())
    else:
        fixed_wordlist.append(word.upper())

print(sentance, '\n', wordlist, '\n', fixed_wordlist)
```